# The only reference that does not show up, why?

Tags: bibtex

I am trying to `\cite` this reference from my `.bib` retrieved from share latex. However, it keeps showing `[?]`. It appears in the `.bib` but not in my reference or my citation. Why

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plainurl}
\bibliography{Name.bib}
\printbibliography, 
\end{document}
```

---

```
@article{Heattransfer,
author = {Incropera, Frank P. and DeWitt, David P.},
edition = {Fourth},
number = {30},
pages = {530},
title = {{Introduction to Heat Transfer}},
url = {https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Heat-Transfer-Frank-Incropera/dp/0471457272},
volume = {0},
year = {2001}
}
```

Comment: Have you run `bibtex` as well as `pdflatex`?

Comment: This reference itself is OK. Look if the previous reverences are OK or not. Yo may have missed a }, for example.

Comment: \begin{document
}\nocite{*}\bibliographystyle{plainurl}
\bibliography{Name.bib}
\printbibliography, this  is the code that I use. The .bib is automatically generated using share latex, therefor it is impossible that there is a problem with only this one and not the other references. I don't really understand why this problem occurs.

Comment: You should have put that example document (with `\documentclass` so people can run it) in your question.  So you are using bibtex not biber, I wil change the tag, but presumably bibtex is failing to generate the bibliography it will have left an error in the bibtex log (`.blg` file which you can see via the overleaf menu)

Comment: Remove the extension `.bib`

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors in your code.

- You missed to call `hyperref` to get a proper url in the bibliography.
- Your command `\bibliography{Name.bib}` is wrong, use it without the extention `.bib`.
- The journal is missing in your bib entry, I added `journal = {missing},`.
- Command `\printbibliography` is used by package `biblatex` and not with bibtex ...

Please see the corrected MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
@article{Heattransfer,
  author  = {Incropera, Frank P. and DeWitt, David P.},
  edition = {Fourth},
  number  = {30},
  pages   = {530},
  title   = {{Introduction to Heat Transfer}},
  url     = {https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Heat-Transfer-Frank-Incropera/dp/0471457272},
  volume  = {0},
  year    = {2001},
  journal = {missing},
} 
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref} % <======================================= for url

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plainurl}
\bibliography{\jobname} % <===================================== no .bib
%\printbibliography % <======================== runs only with biblatex!

\end{document}
```

and its resulting pdf:

[image: resulting bibliography]